# Learning bitcoin from scratch

Tags: introducing-bitcoin

If someone wants to learn bitcoin and blockchain from the cratch please recommend the best resources for     a)free and b) paid sources   thank you   e

Comment: "Learn me a bitcoin", the bitcoin.it wiki, the chaincodelabs curriculum...

Answer (score 1):

> best resources for a)free

1. Bitcoin Stackexchange
2. Reddit: r/bitcoin, r/BitcoinBeginners/, r/lightningnetwork/
3. Bitcointalk
4. GitHub repositories for different Bitcoin projects
5. [IRC channels](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/IRC_channels)
6. Bitcoin dev mailing list: [How can I efficiently search the bitcoin-dev mailing list for discussion of a specific term?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107756/how-can-i-efficiently-search-the-bitcoin-dev-mailing-list-for-discussion-of-a-sp)

Try things, read more about them and ask questions. If starting from scratch first thing you can do is try running and using a Bitcoin full node. Use testnet or regtest for experiments.

You can download [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) or [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/#download) for full node.